# Пререход между Activity в backstack

Tags: android

Имеется стартовая Activity, которая соответственно будет лежать на дне стека. Как правильно осуществить переход к ней из вершины стека, освободив стек от промежуточных Activity, лежащих между ними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, %className);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Определить и послать *Intent*, на получение которого промежуточные *Activity* отреагируют вызовом *finish()*.